# How do I pronounce 1/4 bath, 1/2 and 3/4 bath?

Tags: pronunciation, reading-aloud

> **1/4 bath** is normally just a sink. **1/2 bath** is normally just sink and toilet. **3/4 bath** is normally just a sink, toilet, and shower stall (no tub). A full bath is normally everything.

How do I pronounce these?

I used some software and it read them as "1 slash 4".

Comment: I usually read 1/4 as "quarter", and sometimes "one-fourth".

Comment: @jimsug I phrased my edit as I did because 1) as indicated in the comments and answers already there are multiple ways, 2) there is no single answer, 3) the way it's worded right now could be understood as asking how the OP does pronounce them currently!

Comment: @curious  I would never read that question as asking how the OP pronounces them currently, not because it's not possible, but because it's a bit of a silly question to ask. Also, asking "how do I pronounce these" doesn't preclude the possibility of multiple answers.

Comment: Yes, the Cooperative Principle is relevant here.

Answer (score 10):

You would say it as "[a quarter bath](http://www.ehow.com/info_8465158_14-bath.html)". *Bath* is an abbreviation of *bathroom*, so you could also say "a quarter bathroom".

Similarly, "1/2 bath" is a "half bath" and "3/4 bath" is "A three-quarter bath".

Comment: Thank you so much. What about 1/2? Shoud I read like " half bathroom"? Also 3/4 ? , much more thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, the same logic extends to all the fractions:  a quarter bath, a half bath, and a three-quarters bath.

Comment: @user5036, I agree with Hellion, but I suspect that people would say "a three-quarter bath" with no _s_ on _quarter_.